# Как можно исправить Pascal. 8 строчка

Tags: pascal

```
var
a, b, c, k : integer;
Procedure nod(a, b : integer; var n : integer);
var
r : integer;
begin
repeat
r := a mod b;
a := b; b := r
until b = 0;
n := a
end;
begin
nod(a, b, k);
a := k; b := c;
nod(a, b, k);
if k = 1 then writeln('Числа взаимно простые')
else writeln('Числа не взаимно простые')
end.
```

Comment: В строке `a := b; b := r` нет закрывающего `;`. PS. По странному стечению обстоятельств это именно строка номер 8.

Comment: Pascal исправлять не надо, он давно уже придуман :) А вот заголовок вопроса должен отражать конкретную проблему. Да и задачу нужно описывать, а не "нате, разбирайтесь"

Answer (score 1):

Кто будет числа вводить? [ideone](https://ideone.com/Ftx6mR)

Минимальная коррекция:

```
a := 6;
b := 8;
nod(a, b, k);
if k = 1 then writeln('Числа взаимно простые')
else writeln('Числа не взаимно простые')
```

Если нужно числа менять - сделайте `readln`

Кроме того, `nod` по семантике функция, вот и сделайте её [функцией](https://ideone.com/ZMHVPy)

```
var
  a, b, k : integer;
function nod(a, b : integer): integer;
var
  r : integer;
begin
  repeat
    r := a mod b;
    a := b; 
    b := r;
  until b = 0;
  nod := a; //result
end;

begin
  Writeln('Введите два целых числа');
  Readln(a);
  Readln(b);
  k := nod(a, b);
  if k = 1 then 
     writeln('Числа взаимно простые')
  else 
    writeln('Числа не взаимно простые')
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

Певый раз вижу паскаль, но кажется что нету ";" на 9 строчке, или попробуй удалить переносы строк

Comment: `;` необязателен перед закрывающими элементами, типа `end`